# Assembly Att if statement

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att

I have word from input i want to change (+13 ascii value) letters with ascii code less than 100 - if(char[index]<100) add 13 to char[index] value ( F( ASCII 70)-> S ( ASCII 83)) but it don't work except loop.

c code:

```
char a[4] = "TEXT";
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if(a[i]<100){
        a[i]+=13;
    }
}
```

```
.data
input: .space input_len

_start:
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $input, %ecx
mov $input_len, %edx
int $SYSCALL32

mov %eax,%esp
dec %esp // get rid of \n from input string
mov $0, %ebp //loop index

loop:
cmp $100,input(%ebp) // input is string that user wrote in console
jg et_elseif
add $13, input(%ebp)
et_elseif:
inc %ebp
cmp %esp, %ebp
jl loop
```

how to make proper if statement comparing char in assembly because obviously my code don't work

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to make proper if statement comparing char in assembly because obviously my code don't work

Comment: Pseudo code is good (C even better b/c you can actually test it to make sure its working).  But `if(char[index]<100) add 13` doesn't really reach a level of pseudo code needed to help with your translation.  If you could enrich the pseudo code we might be able to help.  The dec `%esp` and `mov $0 %ebp` are unusual; the `cmp %esp` is odd to say the least -- comparing the stack pointer to the integer you're storing in ebp is suspect.

Comment: `dec %esp` - you usually don't want to misalign the stack pointer relative to a 4-byte boundary.  Also, normally you'd use a call-clobbered register like EAX, ECX, or EDX as your loop counter, although EBP is a general-purpose register so you can use it.  `cmp %esp, %ebp` - That doesn't make sense; ESP is your stack pointer, so this is going to loop your offset until it's equal to ESP, normally near the top of 4GiB virtual address space, so you'll loop just under 2^32 times.

Comment: from docs "On success, the number of bytes read is returned" esp has this value because i wrote this part "mov %eax,%esp"

Comment: Why would you write that value into the stack pointer register?

Comment: Check the sizes of your cmp $100 and add $13.  I suspect it's doing 16 or 32-bit operations rather than the 8 bit you intend.

Comment: Thanks. Solution was cmpb instead of cmp